# Auto redirect for non-logged in users - Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

I'm using google's sign in API for my application and for every request made to the server, I validate that the user is logged in, by sending the token (which I store in session storage) in a post method where the server checks it's valid. However, I also want to do this before a page renders, so a non-logged in user doesn't see the page.

I've read that I should put a script in the  tag to validate the user, but is this the best way to do it?

I'm using Express.js and was wondering if there was a way to do it through this on specific pages, without the need to run a script contained in every HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this would be to middleware function that checks from the session store if the user is logged in and then redirect accordingly

For example :

```
function checkLogin(req, res, next) {
    //check login here
    if (isLoggedin) {
        next();
    } else {
        return res.redirect(req.baseUrl + "/login");
    }
}
```

and when you bind a URL to a function add the check login function as middleware

```
router.get("/",checkLogin,function (req, res, next) {
    //Other Stuff
});
```

Comment: How is this possible to use this on HTML pages which don't have a route?